# ArrayList Mapping in IBatis

Tags: java, ibatis

How should I map multiple columns with List in IBATIS ?

I have a Bean, say :

```
public class AttendanceBean {
    private String user_id;
    private String user_name;
    private List daysArray;
    // setter/getter methods
}
```

Ibatis (select clause in sqlMap):

```
<select id="someName" parameter="param">
   select user_id,user_name,
        day_1,
        day_2,
        day_3,
         ...
         ...
        day_31
    from table1,table2 
    where table1.userid=table2.userid
<select>
```

My question is how I am going to Map AttendanceBean's daysArray with columns `day_1`, `day_2`, ... `day_31` in `ResultMap` even though I can simply write JDBC code for this as follows:

```
List alluser = new ArrayList();
while (rs.next()) {
    AttendanceBean ab = new AttendanceBean();
    ab.setUser_id(rs.getString("USER_ID"));
    ab.setUser_name(rs.getString("USER_NAME"));
    List tempArray = new ArrayList(); 
    for (int i=1;i<=noOfDaysinMonth;i++) {
        tempArray.add(rs.getString("DAY_"+i));
    }
    ab.setDayArray(tempArray);
    alluser.add(ab);
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `daysArray`? `List<Day>` or something? How does `Day` look like?

Comment: How do your tables look like?

Comment: daysArray is List.List of String.. which would come from Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faraz I take the `daysArray` is the number of days a particular user attended? It would be helpful to add some details of your schema. The table that has the number of days also has the user Id as well? **Assuming** you have a similar case you can do the following (this example is based on iBatis version 2.3.4).

```
<select id="retrieveAllUserAttendences" resultMap="exampleUserAttendences">
    SELECT 
    table1.user_id, 
    table1.user_name,
    table2.day
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table1.user_id
</select>

<resultMap id="exampleUserAttendences" class="AttendanceBean" groupBy="user_id">
    <result property="user_id" column="user_id" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String"/>        
    <result property="user_name" column="user_name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String"/> 
    <result property="daysArray" resultMap="sqlMapNamespace.exampleDaysResultMap" />       
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="exampleDaysResultMap" class="java.lang.String">
    <result property="daysArray" column="day_column_name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
</resultMap>
```

Again I must stress this is an example and depends on how you store your data/schema is, however hope this example helps.